# CAEmitterLayer emit continuously in a line

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-animation, particle-system

I am creating a very simple particle system with CoreAnimation.

This is my cell:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spark"];
CAEmitterCell *cell = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
[cell setContents:(id)image.CGImage];
[cell setBirthRate:250.f];
[cell setScale:.25f];
[cell setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.2 blue:0.1 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
[cell setLifetime:5.0f];
```

and layer:

```
CAEmitterLayer *emitterLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
[emitterLayer setEmitterCells:@[cell]];
[emitterLayer setFrame:bounds];
[emitterLayer setRenderMode:kCAEmitterLayerAdditive];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:emitterLayer];
```

Now, I move the emitterLayer's position to wherever I'm touching:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.emitterLayer.emitterPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
}
```

However, the problem is, it doesn't emit the particles continuously. But rather, at regular intervals(dotted as oppose to a line):

[image]

I thought perhaps it's because I'm not animating it. So I tried to add a simple animation to move the emitter from top left to bottom right of the screen just to see if that works:

```
CGPoint startPos = CGPointZero;
CGPoint endPos = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);

CABasicAnimation* ba = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"emitterPosition"];
ba.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPos];
ba.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPos];
ba.duration = .5f;
[emitterLayer addAnimation:ba forKey:nil];
```

What I expected is a line be be formed with particles emitted **continuously**. However, what I see particles being emitted at intervals, like this:[image]

Is it possible to have the emitterLayer follow your touch up and continuously emit these particles like a drawing and not be dotted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect you are looking to achieve (I saw a link in a comment) is probably best achieved without a particle system. What you usually use for this effect depends on individual approach, but I've had success with both.

One, is to create a render buffer: You draw directly onto this buffer with a colour at maximum value. This could be a `UIView` for instance. At a timed interval, you decrease every pixel value in this view by a percentage (say 0.05%). New pixels added start bright and fade over time this way, so you have no gaps between points. This is CPU intensive!

The other is to create a 'trianglestrip': you will need to go into a lower level graphics API for this such as OpenGL. The idea is that you create a section of triangles (or quads) that form a 'ribbon' under your finger. Each new section that is added begins fading to 0% alpha and is then removed. There is an implementation of this technique in **cocos2d** which is called [CCMotionStreak](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCMotionStreak.html) that is perfect for this. The benefit is that you supply a texture (as you would a particle system) so it keeps designers happy

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest removing the animation and to create the line effect via the `CAEmitterCell`'s `velocity` and `emissionLongitude` properties:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spark"];
CAEmitterCell *cell = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
[cell setContents:(id)image.CGImage];
[cell setBirthRate:250.f];
[cell setScale:.25f];
[cell setColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.2 blue:0.1 alpha:0.5].CGColor];
[cell setLifetime:5.0f];
[cell setEmissionLongitude:M_PI_4]; //The emission angle
[cell setVelocity:500]; //adjust as needed, together with BirthRate


CAEmitterLayer *emitterLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
[emitterLayer setEmitterCells:@[cell]];
[emitterLayer setFrame:bounds];
[emitterLayer setRenderMode:kCAEmitterLayerAdditive];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:emitterLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks awfully like the pattern you'd see using an ease-in ease-out animation curve, which I think is the default for CAAnimations. The points are closer together at either end, suggesting it is slower at the beginning and end.

Change the timing function of the animation to linear and you should see the effect you want.

To get a continuous line of emitters the only thing I could get to work was to slow the animation down, which doesn't really give the right effect. It looks like moving the emitter position skips a few renders, I'm not sure why.

You also need to play with the scaling a bit and probably use a CAShapeLayer to draw the actual line you're after.

In fact, a better solution is probably to use a smaller emitter layer which you move along at the end of the line, with a CAShapeLayer which you animate the `strokeEnd` of to leave the drawing in there.

Comment: Tried that however that doesn't fix it. There's still gaps. I'm looking for a way to make it so there's no gaps. A continuous line.

Comment: Like a fire moving along a fuse or something?

Comment: Ah! In that case I misunderstood you question. Let me have a look and get back to you

Comment: cool, thanks! if it helps here's a video showing what i mean exactly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shirth1OjRE#t=167 (at 2:45) .

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your `birthRate` is set way too low. Try changing it from `250.f` to something like `1500.f` and post the results.